# How can I print html page in Landscape mode in my Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, printing, vuejs2

I can print HTML page in Landscape mode like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">

<style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
/* @page {size:landscape}  */ 
@media print {
    @page {size: A4 landscape;}
}
</style>


<title>Landscape</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>

<body>
<img src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/knowledge_graph_logo.png?201812022340">

</body>

</html>
```

But I can't find the way how to print a Vue component page in landscape mode. I'm using Printd component to print page in my project. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/printd)
Even though I set landscape mode, always be set portrait mode.

How can I set landscape mode programmatically?

```
<template>
    <div ref="printMe">
        <img src="https://www.apple.com/ac/structured-data/images/knowledge_graph_logo.png?201812022340">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Printd } from 'printd';

export default {
    mounted() {
        this.print();
    },
    methods: {      
        print() {
            const p = new Printd();
            p.print(
                this.$refs.printMe,
                `@media print {
                    @page {size: A4 landscape;}
                }`,
            );
        },
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
@media print {
    @page {
        size: landscape;
    }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

- The media query you use is defined to always mean the full page -
  that’s what its meant to do.
- You can’t put individual elements on a page into “landscape” mode, that’s only 
  possible for pages.
- So you will have to change the dimensions of the element manually to those that 
  fit your needs. See the below style

  ```
  . orientation {
    width: 400px /* normal width */
  }
  @media print {
    .orientation {
      width: 100% /* print width */
    }
  }
  ```